# Is there a way to remove elements from lists that starts with

Tags: r

below is the lists. Is there way to remove elements that starts with `asd` ?

```
x1 <- list(asd1 = structure(19116, class = "Date"), asd2 = TRUE, 
           a3 = structure(19116, class = "Date"), MainNavBar = "V", 
           btnGetDWData = structure(0L, class = c("integer", "shinyActionButtonValue"
           )), sd = "Info", fd = NULL, 
           fd = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
x1[!grepl("^asd",names(x1))]
```

Comment: As a minor comment, ```"asd"```  should be ```"^asd"``` since OP wants to remove elements starting with asd.

Comment: @maarvd You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
x1[startsWith(names(x1) , "asd")] <- NULL
```